# d3.js force layout drag and maintain the positions in the Localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

As i want to maintain the drag positions in the local storage. So when i refresh the page i can retain the position in the force layout in d3.js

Can any one please give me an idea on this. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Save the node positions?

Comment: Yes i want to save the drag positions in the local storage.

Comment: So what's the problem? The positions are determined by the x and y attributes, all you need to do is save them.

Comment: ok but how come? where can i save the positions?

Comment: You say that you want to save them in local storage, don't you?

Comment: Yes want to save them in local storage

Comment: Well there are lots of tutorials on that, e.g. [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: its not working out.